# Mock secure origin for auth0-spa-js in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, auth0

Trying to setup jest tests around auth0-spa-js but getting error 'auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin' when attempting to await createAuth0Client(config). Whats the best way to mock secure origin in jest tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocking the module worked great for me.

```js
jest.mock('@auth0/auth0-spa-js');
```

Answer (score 22):

After digging into auth0 code to see what it wants, i gave it global.crypto.subtle = {} and it seems to have satisfied it, the error has gone, the tests pass:

```
const JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM

Object.defineProperty(global.self, 'crypto', {
  value: {
    getRandomValues: arr => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length)
  }
})
global.crypto.subtle = {} // this gets around the 'auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin' error
```

Comment: Please explain where you put that code and how to let Jest know that code exists. I keep hitting a wall trying to fix the crypto thing and after trying like 10 possible solutions, nothing works. Thanks.

Comment: @demian85 You can put this code somewhere like `/jest/setupTests.js` and then in your jest config (e.g. `jest.config.js`) put the following: ```setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest/setupTests.js'],```

Comment: FWIW I got this working with my `src/setupTests.js` file only containing `window.crypto = { subtle: {} };`